# Most Product Views by last day and last month with views

Tags: magento-1.9, product, products-view, view

I am trying to get most viewed products for last month and last day by using this code but apparently both are returning me same no. of views

**Last Day:**

```
$from = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(' -1 day'));
            $to=now();
```

**Last Month:**

```
 $from  = new DateTime("first day of last month");
            $to = new DateTime("last day of last month");

             from ->format('Y-m-d'); // 2012-02-01
            $to->format('Y-m-d'); // 2012-02-29
```

**CODE:**

```
 $productCount = 5;
          $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
           $products=Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->setStoreId($storeId)
                    ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
                    ->addViewsCount()
                    ->addViewsCount($from, $to)
                    ->setPageSize($productCount);

            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')
                    ->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')
                    ->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);
            return $products;
```

Along with this I also need to get product view count for all the time.

**EDIT:** With certain fixes in my phtml file above code works for last day and all time. But the last month is giving me error on this line

```
->addViewsCount($from, $to)
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying this code worked:

**CODE:**

```
public function getMostViewedProducts($requested) {
         Mage::log($requested,null,'size.log',true);
        $productCount = 5;
        $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
        if ($requested == "last_day") {
            $from = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(' -1 day'));
            $to = now();
            $products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->setStoreId($storeId)
                    ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
                    ->addViewsCount()
                    ->addViewsCount($from, $to)
                    ->setPageSize($productCount);

            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')
                    ->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')
                    ->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);
            return $products;
        } else if ($requested == "last_month") {
            $month_ini = new DateTime("first day of last month");
            $month_end = new DateTime("last day of last month");

            $from=$month_ini->format('Y-m-d'); // 2012-02-01
            $to=$month_end->format('Y-m-d'); // 2012-02-29
            $products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->setStoreId($storeId)
                    ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
                    ->addViewsCount()
                    ->addViewsCount($from, $to)
                    ->setPageSize($productCount);

            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')
                    ->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')
                    ->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);
            return $products;
        } else if($requested==""){
            $products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->setStoreId($storeId)
                    ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
                    ->addViewsCount()
                    //->addViewsCount()
                    ->setPageSize($productCount);

            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')
                    ->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')
                    ->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);
            foreach($products as $a){
              //  Mage::log($a->getData(),null,'size.log',true);//exit;
            }
            return $products;
        }
    }
```